# Create error when calling function does not use the right number of arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have this function in javascript.

```
function func_name(param_1, param_2)
{
  //blah blah
}
```

Sometimes, I carelessly call it this way by supplying 1 parameter instead of 2.

```
func_name(aa);
```

However, javascript does not produce an error when the script is run. How can I make javascript produce an error or warning when the script is run? This will help one catch bugs more easily.

I am using node.js v6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `arguments` object. Each function has an internal object called `args`, which is an array like object (has a length property) and contains the parameters which we use when we call the function.

```
function func_name(param_1, param_2){
    if(arguments.length!==2){
        // Here you can throw an error.
    }
}
```

For further info, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: It's `arguments` in JavaScript, not `args`.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. Just wondering. Is it possible to check the data type of the arguments (string or integer) and throw an error if the type is not right? Can this be done in javascript? It will make JS less prone to bugs.

Comment: @user91579631 If you're unfamiliar with JavaScript, you are probably better off starting with something like [MDN's JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: @user91579631 ofcourse you can using the `typeof` operator for primitive values and `instanceof` operator for reference values. Please note, the there isn't any type for integers in JavaScript. There is only one primitive type for numbers, which is called `Number`.

Comment: @user91579631 perhaps [typescript](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-typescript/) might interest you. It allows you to specify datatypes for variables, thus making it less prone to errors

Comment: @sid-m, looks good! I wonder if there will be a wave of migration to typescript.